# hamming distance through recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I have a problem I'm supposed to solve using recursion:

Hamming distance. The Hamming distance between two bit strings of length `n` is equal to the number of bits in which the two strings differ. Write a program that reads in an integer `k` and a bit string `s` from the command line, and prints out all bit strings that have Hamming distance at most k from `s`. For example if `k` is `2` and `s` is `0000` then your program should print out:

```
0011 0101 0110 1001 1010 1100
```

Hint: choose `k` of the `N` bits in `s` to flip.

I have no idea where to begin could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: A naive way to do it would be to generate all possible n-bit strings and test their hamming distance from `s`, returning only the ones where `hamming()` <= `k`. What have you tried?

Comment: This looks fun! You should try it!

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance, they even have a python based solution there.

Comment: @Ashiwini that algorithm is only for calculating the Hamming distance of two strings?!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Post something that you've tried. Asking us to do your homework for you is not why we're here

Comment: why 0000 is not in the output? Its Hamming distance is 0 from `s` (from itself) that is less than k=2. Or does the actual assignment say that they should have Hamming distance *exactly* k (not *at most* k) from s?

Comment: Good question. I thought he means Hamming distance == k

Answer (score 2):

To solve a problem recursively, you need to do some small amount of work that lets you break it down into a similar -- but smaller -- problem.

In your case, you have a string i.e. a sequence of characters. The set of strings that differ from S in k places consists of some strings which either agree with S in the first place or disagree. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Code is as follows. The basic idea is just to consider the string t = s[:-1]. You concatenate all strings with Hamming distance less than k-1 for t with a flip of s[-1], plus you concatenate all strings with Hamming distance equal k for t with s[-1].

```
def flip(c): return str(1-int(c))

def flip_s(s, i):
   t =  s[:i]+flip(s[i])+s[i+1:]
   return t

def hamming(s, k):
 if k>1:
      c = s[-1]
      s1 = [y+c for y in hamming(s[:-1], k)] if len(s) > k else []
      s2 = [y+flip(c) for y in hamming(s[:-1], k-1)]
      r = []
      r.extend(s1)
      r.extend(s2)
      return r
 else:
   return [flip_s(s,i) for i in range(len(s))]


>>> print hamming("0000", 2)
>>> ['1100', '1010', '0110', '1001', '0101', '0011']
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `H(s, k)` be a set of bit strings of length `len(s)` that have
Hamming distance `k` from `s` then we could compute it easily using
smaller sets `H(s[:-1], k-1)` and `H(s[:-1], k)`, where `s[:-1]` is
`s` without the last character:

```
def H(s, k):
    # invariant: H yields `len(s)`-bit strings that have k-bits flipped
    if len(s) < k:
        return  # produce nothing; can't flip k bits
    if k == 0:
        yield s  # only one n-bit string has Hamming distance 0 from s (itself)
    else:
        for s_k_minus_one_flipped in H(s[:-1], k - 1):
            yield s_k_minus_one_flipped + flip(s[-1])  # flip last bit
        for s_k_flipped in H(s[:-1], k):
            yield s_k_flipped + s[-1]  # don't flip last bit

def flip(bit):
    assert bit == "0" or bit == "1"
    return "0" if bit == "1" else "1"

print(" ".join(H("0000", 2)))
# -> 0011 0101 1001 0110 1010 1100
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/575C8P)